# How to check if a database and tables exist in sql server in a vb .net project?

Tags: sql, sql-server, vb.net, sql-server-2008

Can anyone tell me how I would go about checking if a database and tables exists in sql server from a vb.net project? What I want to do is check if a database exists (preferably in an 'If' statement, unless someone has a better way of doing it) and if it does exist I do one thing and if it doesn't exist I create the database with the tables and columns. Any help on this matter would be greatly appreciated.

Edit:

The application has a connection to a server. When the application runs on a PC I want it to check that a database exists, if one exists then it goes and does what it's supposed to do, but if a database does NOT exist then it creates the database first and then goes on to do what it's supposed to do. So basically I want it to create the database the first time it runs on a PC and then go about it's business, then each time it runs on the PC after that I want it to see that the database exists and then go about it's business. The reason I want it like this is because this application will be on more than one PC, I only want the database and tables created once, (the first time it runs on a PC) and then when it runs on a different PC, it sees that the database already exists and then run the application using the existing database created on the other PC.

Comment: I assume your app must already have a connection to the server? This to me sounds like a deployment instead of something you should embed in an application. You can check sys.databases

Comment: I don't think the connection to the server is the issue. I'm assuming the application could create a database & tables on the fly, if they don't already exist.

Comment: This shows you how to check: http://kellyschronicles.wordpress.com/2009/02/16/check-if-sql-database-exists-on-a-server-with-vb-net/, I'd post it as an answer but it'd just be a copy n paste job.

Comment: @Tanner you're link worked great, thanks for your help. Problem solved.

Comment: @Coder92 no problem, I'll add it as a referenced answer shortly

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can query SQL Server to check for the existence of objects.

To check for database existence you can use this query:

```sql
SELECT * FROM master.dbo.sysdatabases WHERE name = 'YourDatabase'
```

To check for table existence you can use this query against your target database:

```sql
SELECT * FROM sys.tables WHERE name = 'YourTable' AND type = 'U'
```

This below link shows you how to check for database existence is SQL Server using VB.NET code:

### [Check if SQL Database Exists on a Server with vb.net](http://kellyschronicles.wordpress.com/2009/02/16/check-if-sql-database-exists-on-a-server-with-vb-net/)

Referenced code from above link:

> ```
> Public Shared Function CheckDatabaseExists(ByVal server As String, _
>                                            ByVal database As String) As Boolean
>     Dim connString As String = ("Data Source=" _
>                 + (server + ";Initial Catalog=master;Integrated Security=True;"))
>
>     Dim cmdText As String = _
>        ("select * from master.dbo.sysdatabases where name=\’" + (database + "\’"))
>
>     Dim bRet As Boolean = false
>
>     Using sqlConnection As SqlConnection = New SqlConnection(connString)
>         sqlConnection.Open
>         Using sqlCmd As SqlCommand = New SqlCommand(cmdText, sqlConnection)
>             Using reader As SqlDataReader = sqlCmd.ExecuteReader
>                 bRet = reader.HasRows
>             End Using
>         End Using
>     End Using
>
>     Return bRet
>
> End Function
> ```

You could perform the check in another way, so it's done in a single call by using an `EXISTS` check for both the database and a table:

```sql
IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM master.dbo.sysdatabases WHERE name = 'YourDatabase')
BEGIN
    -- Database creation SQL goes here and is only called if it doesn't exist
END

-- You know at this point the database exists, so check if table exists

IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.tables WHERE name = 'YourTable' AND type = 'U')
BEGIN
    -- Table creation SQL goes here and is only called if it doesn't exist
END
```

By calling the above code once with parameters for database and table name, you will know that both exist.

Answer (score 3):

Connect to the master database and select

```
SELECT 1 FROM master..sysdatabases WHERE name = 'yourDB'
```

and then on the database

```
SELECT 1 FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES  WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'yourTable'
```

i dont know the exact vb syntax but you only have to check the recordcount on the result

Comment: This will work but creates problem on the code side where you need to check for NULL (Nothing) if the database or table don't exist. Better use IF EXISTS(.....) SELECT 1 ELSE SELECT 0 so a return is always guarateed.

Comment: Oh the irony of @deterministicFail being corrected on code that didn't deterministically fail...

Comment: @Steve in my last sentence i assume to check the count on the resultset. So the if would be in vb and not in T-SQL

Comment: Don't forget to check the schema too.  `AND TABLE_SCHEMA = 'yourSchema'`

Comment: The point is that you could obtain the result 1 or 0 without getting a DataSet back. Just an ExecuteScalar it is more performant. But, in this context, it is not really important. Just to let you know.

Comment: If you `SELECT 1` and the `WHERE` clause is nothing, you'll get a null that you need to handle.  You may want to use `select count(1)` to get a 0 or a 1

Comment: if you select 1 and the where claus is nothing, you'll get nothing! try it in your management studio `Select 1 from table where 1=0`. And the trick i suggest is to test the number of records you are fetching not the result itself

Comment: @deterministicFail you said the same thing I did.

Comment: @Dan Andrews No, there is a difference between no rows in the resultset or a row with the value NULL

Comment: Please try with `select count(1)` in SQL Server, I think you'll be surprised. `Select count(1) from table where 1=0` returns 0, not null.

Answer (score 3):

For tables and other objects inside a database, I usually do it this way but it's really personal preference.

```
IF OBJECT_ID('dbo.blah') IS NOT NULL
BEGIN

END
```

For VB.NET, I'd wrap this in a stored procedure and call that. I'm sure there are also ways to do this with Linq.

Answer (score 2):

You can use This query for check database

IF DB_Id('YourDatabaseName') IS NOT NULL

BEGIN

```
PRINT 'DB EXISTS'
```

END

ELSE

BEGIN

```
PRINT 'DB  NOT EXISTS'
```

END

Answer (score 1):

```
Friend Function CheckDatabaseExists(server As String, database As String) As Boolean
    Dim connString As String = "Data Source=" + server + ";Initial Catalog=master;Integrated Security=SSPI"

    Dim cmdText As String = "select * from master.dbo.sysdatabases where name='" + database + "'"

    Dim bRet As Boolean = False

    Using sqlConnection As SqlConnection = New SqlConnection(connString)
        sqlConnection.Open
        Using sqlCmd As SqlCommand = New SqlCommand(cmdText, sqlConnection)
            Using reader As SqlDataReader = sqlCmd.ExecuteReader
                bRet = reader.HasRows
            End Using
        End Using
    End Using

    Return bRet

End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

```
   Public Function SQLDatabaseExist(ByVal DefaultConnectionString As String, ByVal DataBaseName As String) As Boolean
    Try
        'CREATE DATABASE
        Dim SqlString As String = ""
        SqlString = "SELECT CASE WHEN EXISTS (SELECT name FROM master.dbo.sysdatabases WHERE name = N'" & DataBaseName & "') THEN CAST (1 AS BIT) ELSE CAST (0 AS BIT) END"
        Dim ExcRet As Integer = 0
        Using connection As New SqlConnection(DefaultConnectionString)
            Dim command As New SqlCommand(SqlString, connection)
            command.Connection.Open()
            ExcRet = command.ExecuteScalar()
            command.Connection.Close()
            command.Dispose()
        End Using
        Return ExcRet
    Catch ex As Exception
        Return False
    End Try
End Function
```

Comment: 'Sample Default Connection String
    Dim DefaultConnectionString As String = "Data Source=localhost\SQLSERVER2008;Initial Catalog=Master; User ID=SA; Password='123123'; MultipleActiveResultSets=false; Connect Timeout=15;Encrypt=False;Packet Size=4096;"
    'Notice the initial catalog in the connection string must be master!