# VB.net Checking if database exists before connecting to it

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, vb.net, sql-server-2012

I [found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/679000/how-to-check-if-a-database-exists-in-sql-server) the following query in order to find out if a database table was created already or not:

```
if db_id('thedbName') is not null
   --code mine :)
   print 'db exists'
else
   print 'nope'
```

Now I am wanting to use that same query within my VB.net application. This is the code I currently have elsewhere that connects to the database (that I am wanting to see if its there before doing all this):

```
Dim cn As SqlConnection = New SqlConnection("Data Source=DAVIDSDESKTOP;" & _
                                            "Initial Catalog=thedbName;" & _
                                            "Integrated Security=True;" & _
                                            "Pooling=False")

    Dim sql As String = "if db_id('thedbName') is not null " & vbCrLf & _
                            "Print() 'exists' " & vbCrLf & _
                        "else " & vbCrLf & _
                            "Print() 'nope'"

    Dim cmd As SqlCommand = New SqlCommand(sql, cn)

    cmd.Connection.Open()
    Dim blah As String = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
    cmd.Connection.Close()
```

Of course the issue with this is that I have to know the database name first in order to connect to the database.

I then seem to be able to connect to the *master* database using this:

```
Dim cn As SqlConnection = New SqlConnection("Data Source=DAVIDSDESKTOP;" & _
                                            "Integrated Security=True;" & _
                                            "Pooling=False")

    Dim sql As String = "if db_id('thedbName') is not null " & vbCrLf & _
                            "Print() 'exists' " & vbCrLf & _
                        "else " & vbCrLf & _
                            "Print() 'nope'"

    Dim cmd As SqlCommand = New SqlCommand(sql, cn)

    cmd.Connection.Open()
    Dim blah As String = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
    cmd.Connection.Close()
```

But that query seems to throw an error on **Dim blah As String = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()** of:

> Additional information: Incorrect syntax near ')'.

So I'm not all sure what I am missing in order to correct the issue with the query?

**Need to know how to have the query come back and say 'exists' or 'nope'**

Comment: Did you first run the query on your database before including it in your code?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to check if a database and tables exist in sql server in a vb .net project?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25162815/how-to-check-if-a-database-and-tables-exist-in-sql-server-in-a-vb-net-project)

Comment: Yes the query works just fine using SQL management studio.

Comment: @MrGadget not applicable since I am also wanting to return a 'exists' or 'nope'. No solution in that way in the link to the other post.

Comment: should be just `Print exists` without the parenthesis

Comment: @StealthRT, Remove `()` following the `PRINT` keyword.  I can't say how the script could work in SSMS due to the syntax error.

Comment: @StealthRT The answer is there.  `SELECT * FROM sys.tables WHERE name = 'YourTable' AND type = 'U'` If that returns zero rows, no database. Pass that into your command, and cmd.ExecuteNonQuery() returns an integer (not a string) of number of rows.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change `Print()` to `Print` (remove the parentheses.)

---

Better, don't use `Print` at all, use `select`.

```
Dim sql As String = "if db_id('thedbName') is not null " & vbCrLf & _
                        "select 'exists' " & vbCrLf & _
                    "else " & vbCrLf & _
                        "select 'nope'"

Dim blah As String = CType(cmd.ExecuteScalar(), string)
```

`ExecuteNonQuery` returns the number of affected rows for updates and inserts. But what you are executing *is* a query.

`ExecuteScalar` returns the first column of the first row selected. The query above only returns one row with one value, so that's what it will return.

Comment: Thanks for spotting that. No error not but it keeps returning **-1** and not 'exists' or 'nope'

Comment: **Great Scott!** Ha. Thanks for the example code. It now works just fine!

Answer (score 0):

or do it like this

```
select * from sys.databases where [name] = 'thedbName'
```

if it returns a row, then the database exists, if not then it doesn't.

To check if a table exists within a database, use this

```
select * from sys.objects where [name] = 'theTableName' and type_desc = 'USER_TABLE'
```